# Geometry nodes: change points rotation

Tags: node-editor, geometry

I can't understand how to tell geo-nodes to face these bolts outwards. They are propagated on cylinder vertexes, which have no info about vectors (unlike faces).

[image]

Comment: U tried align rotation to vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by face outwards, but I think you could use an align rotation to vector, with the position as the vector attribute, like this. If you want to use this technique on other meshes you might need to fiddle with the rotation axis[image]:[image: EXAMPLE]

Comment: That's exacly what i was searching for! Tried to touch that node, but cannot fully understand how to operate with it. Thanx!

Comment: And, by the way, to face only in one local dimension, you have to change axis in the "pivot" menu of that node.